# Kotlin перебор параметров класса и их значений

Tags: kotlin

Есть класс с некоторым количеством параметров. Допустим, мы хотим переопределить метод `toString` чтобы нам возвращалась строка в формате похожем на JSON включающая все параметры класса (чтобы не переписывать функцию при добавлении новых параметров). Каким образом я могу перебрать все параметры класса, чтобы реализовать это?

Я пробовал использовать `kotlin-reflect` для этих целей, и смог получить параметры класса с их типами (что меня устраивает), но так я не могу получить значение самого параметра, т.к. `property.getValue()` требует экземпляр класса:

```
class User(
   var name: String,
   var age: Int,
   var number: String
) {
   
   override fun toString(): String {

      var json = ""

      for (property in this::class.memberProperties) {
           json += "\"${property.name}\": \"${property.getValue(???)}\","
      }

      return "{$json}"

   }

}
```

Что я упускаю и есть ли более оптимальное решение задачи?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае можно получать значения через геттер

```
for (property in this::class.memberProperties) {
    json += "\"${property.name}\": \"${property.getter.call(this)}\","
}
```